# Is the available disk space stored in the sql server (2000) master database?

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to monitor the space left on drives that various databases sit on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to use extended stored procedures for this if you want to access this information through SQL for some reason. Example here using `EXEC master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives` (Scroll down for the SQL2000 version) http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1706